# Confusion about node pointer assignment

Tags: c++, pointers

My code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
   double data;
   Node* next;
};

int main(){
   Node* a;
   a = new Node;
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding why the assignment would work for a pointer. Because `a` is type `Node*` but the new node is type `Node`.

At the beginning of my class, I was taught that pointer assignment needs to always be an address.

For example:

```cpp
int * x;
int y = 5;
```

This would be allowed:

```cpp
x = &5;
```

But this wouldn't:

```cpp
x = y;
```

So, by that same logic, shouldn't the assignment of `Node* a;` be:

```cpp
a = &(new Node);
```

Instead of:

```cpp
a = new Node;
```

?

Comment: Sounds like you could do with a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: "This would be allowed:" Did you actually mean `x = &y;` instead of `x = &5;` ?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `new`, it creates a new object and returns a pointer to that object. It is quite common to store that pointer in a pointer variable. You would use `& new(...)` if it returned a reference to the newly-created object. But it doesn't.

Comment: also, what is the reason for making it "new Node" instead of "new Node()" with the parentheses? thank you for taking your time to answer, I am a student transitioning from Java to C++.

Comment: @TimSon, There's only a small difference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Answer (score 2):

> but the new Node is type Node.

is absolutely wrong. This is not Java. `new Node` returns a pointer to a freshly allocated on heap Node.

Comment: C++ is not Java, that is true. But in this case, `new` behaves similarly in both C++ and Java.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every assignment requires **correct type**. Either you provide left argument of the exact same type as the variable you assign to, or of a type you can convert from. E.g.

```
int x = 5; //here x is a type of int and 5 is also an int
```

or

```
double w = 3; //here w is a type of double and 3 is again int but int can be converted to double
```

in contrary

```
int z = 3.2; //won't compile because 3.2 is a float and floats have to be explicitly casted to ints.
```

Now, with your code, `Node*` is a type you read as `Node pointer` and `new` allocates memory on heap, creates new object and return its address which in this case is also `Node pointer`. Types match and everything works.

Comment: "or of a type you can convert from." Are you aware of the fact, that with this, you likely triggered a really complex follow-up confusion about C++ complex conversion rules in doubt? :)